# How to use find_in_set in objection js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, objection.js

I have a column that has comma seperated string, and I need to find the exact values that contains in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider categories containes comma seperated values like "Food, Clothings, ecommerce".

```
Model.select(['id', 'categories']).whereRaw(`FIND_IN_SET('Clothings')`, categories)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below syntax to find a value which will match in whereIn

`knex.select('name').from('users').whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])`

Outputs:
`select name from users where id in (1, 2, 3)`

[Docs](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-whereIn)